# In MS Excel Is there any way to use number formatting on entries with a mix of letters and numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to decimal justify a list using the number formatting, but the numbers in question happen to have letters in them, and they're being ignored.  Is there any way to get Excel to recognize letters as numbers?

this can be done in Word using Decimal Tabs, but I need it in Excel for the project I'm working on.

Comment: Not without parsing the data with formulas and/or vba and then right aligning the cell either manually or through the same vba.

Comment: Can you post some examples of the numbers, and what your expected output is?